# How do I compare an element in the list with a string value in python?

Tags: python

```
message1=changes.split(" ")
if message1[0] == 'D'
changes="deleted"
```

I tried to compare it in different ways  and  I am getting invalid syntax errors :( I am using python2.3.  Could you please help?

Comment: Where is indent before `changes="deleted"` and colon after `if message1[0] == 'D'` AnD overall this is a faulty syntax!

Comment: Since you're using Python 2 [this tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial) may be more suitable. But you probably should try to upgrade to a more recent version of Python - 2.3 is _ancient_!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is fine but the syntax is wrong **you forgot the ':' after the if statement and to indent the content**.
here's an exemple :

```
changes = "D A C"
messages1 = changes.split(" ")
if messages1[0] == "D":
    print "message1 == 'D'"
    #..... you logic here
```

I recommend you look at this [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).